# Is Google Shopping Feed option not available by default in magento 1.8

Tags: magento, configure, google-shopping-api

> HI i have a store in magneto1.1.8

. **I want to use google shopping**

> but when i go to under google api i cant see any google shopping
>   option.

So can you please tell me

> do i need to install some extension or there is some setting which i
>   need to enable to view google shopping option
>
> Also is there any free extension for this if i need to install

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Magento's new version 1.8.1 removes Google Checkout payment option due to Google announcing the product's end of life in November of 2013.
So not display in `Google Api` tab in System->Configuration.
If you want to intigrate google checkout in Magento 1.8.1 than download 1.8.0 version form http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/.
in that copy folling files to your magento 1.8.1 with same location

- app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout(Directory).
- app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googlecheckout.xml(File).
- app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googlecheckout(Directory).
- lib/googlecheckout(Directory).

Now Google Checkout option display in your New Magento 1.8.1.

Comment: i am talking about google data feed not google checkout

Comment: For that use http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-shopping-feed.html extension.